# How can I have multiple active Windows sessions simultaneously?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

- When I log on to my computer remotely with Remote Desktop the local user is locked out.
- When the local user logs in my Remote Desktop session is interrupted.

I want to get rid of this limitation. How?

Comment: What version of windows are you using?

Comment: I'm willing to get any version I need to make this work.

Comment: Answer differs depending on how much control you or the local user want. Control same session (you both on same desktop), or multiple logon?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need a server version of Windows. This is strictly a licensing issue - regardless of whatever technical hacks are available.

A Windows server will then allow for 2 concurrent RDP sessions in administrative mode, after which you need remote desktop services (terminal services) client/device licenses for more concurrent connections (generally known as TS CALs).

Answer (score 11):

In two words : you can't. This artificial limitation by Microsoft is designed to force you to update to a Server version of the operating system.

However, if you're using XP, you might rollback back one system dll to a version dating to before Microsoft had this brilliant idea. See the two following articles for slightly different instructions on how to do this:

[Concurrent Remote Desktop Sessions in Windows XP SP2](http://sig9.com/articles/concurrent-remote-desktop)
[Enabling Multiple Remote Desktop Sessions in Windows XP Professional and Media Center Edition 2005](http://www.golod.com/2005/10/enabling-multiple-remote-desktop-sessions-in-windows-xp-professional-and-media-center-edition-2005/)

Be careful, and don't forget first to take backups and create a system restore point.

**EDIT** : Now also for all Windows versions :
[Enable Concurrent Sessions on Windows 8.1, Windows 8, Windows 7, Windows Vista and Windows XP](http://digiex.net/guides-reviews/guides-tutorials/windows-guides/1879-enable-concurrent-sessions-windows-7-windows-vista-windows-xp-termsrv-dll.html)

Comment: Worth noting the link in the edit does not mention Windows 8 or 8.1 as supported. Patches do exist for 8 and 8.1 if you do your research.