# Multiple Remote Desktop Sessions with Windows

Tags: windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop, windows-server-2003, active-directory

I'm using Active Directory with Windows XP clients and Server 2003 as the AD. Is there a way to allow a local user to be logged in and allow an admin to login as well without one of the sessions being dropped?

Comment: Are you talking about having two users actively logged into the XP Clients at the same time, or the 2003 Server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I have multiple active sessions simultaneously (Windows)?](http://superuser.com/questions/43776/how-can-i-have-multiple-active-sessions-simultaneously-windows)

Comment: The XP Machine. I would like a lesser(not admin) user logged in doing typical work and then the administrator would be able to log in to manage the box like install updates or whatever while they are still logged in. Is that possible?

Comment: Like Luke said in this answer (as well as the answers to the duplicate I linked), Windows client versions (XP, etc.) only allow one active user session at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have 2 admins connected in Remote Administration mode onto a Server 2003 product, but not into XP natively. There have been products before that would let multiple users connect to a Windows XP Home or Pro machine, but it violates the EULA, and the users were cautioned against installing certain updates, and keeping certain files locked. So yes, you can, but it obviously isn't recommended.

When using Remote Desktop with Windows XP natively, it will kick the current user off, no matter what. You can, however, enable the Telnet server if you know the commands to run, and that will run in the background of the machine

Comment: Oh ok. So I just need to remove Admin powers from the user? I was trying to run an admin user and a non-admin user.

Comment: If you remove Admin powers, they cannot remote desktop to a server, unless it is a Terminal server. If you remove Admin powers from an XP system, they must be manually added to the Remote Users group, but you're again, limited to one person, whether it's remote or local

Comment: So using the Windows Based Remote Desktop System it is NOT possible to have more then 2 users logged in at a time?

Comment: Correct, unless you have a Terminal Services Server running, in which case you need extra CALs for each user. When using it with Windows XP, only one person can see a desktop at a time

Comment: Which seems a bit annoying to be fair, I could do with that at work haha.

Comment: @RossDoughty Well, Microsoft DOES have RDP servers available, called Terminal Services.. But they're bloody expensive