# Using another computer's resource (windows), hiding windows

Tags: windows, remote, multiple-users

Linux supports multiple X servers, but I was wondering if there is any proprietary software that let you do something similar for Windows 7 (Pro). I am trying to run some app 24/7 on my family member's computer remotely without making it get into their way. More specifically, the app runs on Firefox, but I want the window to be hidden so that they do not touch it by an accident.

Comment: Is minimizing to the system tray enough? You could use [Trayconizer](http://www.whitsoftdev.com/trayconizer/) to put any application in the system tray. It won't hide it completely, but it should make it a bit less visible.

Comment: could this be relevant, see if anything here helps http://superuser.com/questions/428079/multiple-remote-desktop-sessions-with-windows

Comment: Both of them are great answers. I would have gone with Trayconizer since that is the simple solution. Thank you.