# Remote desktop to machine without locking out the user

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-control

I am looking to rdp into a remote machine, but still have that machine unlocked. The default behavior is to take the destination machine to a lock screen. I have tried remote assistance, but it does not deal with multiple monitors/displays. I simple want the normal rdp sessions to not lockout the local machine when the connection is created.

I have seen reference to tscon, but that is not present in windows 8.1 (The connection is Windows 8.1 -> 8.1 pro & Win 7 pro) It's also unclear from various examples whether that simple didn't logout the user, or actually left the local machine unlocked & visible during the session, but either way it is not available.

Regarding 3rd party tools, I have tried avaton/air-display, ultra-vnc, and teamviewer, and each have significant lag  beyond that experienced in rdp.

Comment: not possible with the remote desktop without a registry hack which is well documented.  Multiple users cannot be logged into non-Windows Server OSs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable concurrent Remote Desktop Sessions in Windows 8 Pro](http://superuser.com/questions/511848/how-to-enable-concurrent-remote-desktop-sessions-in-windows-8-pro)

Comment: teamviewer significant lag? I use it on very hi-res multiple monitor setups and I have never had problems with it as long as bandwidth is there. 4 Monitor setups with resolutions 3x greater than 1080HD...

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe of the cited question because I am not looking to have multiple RDP sessions. And I am not looking to have multiple users logged in. This would be the same user logged in at the machine locally. When I make the RDP connection, it doesn't log out the local user, just goes to a lock screen. The session is still there, all apps as they were. I don't want the lock screen though. I want the local machine to show what is happening in the RDP sessions.

Comment: Did you somehow solved this @Promethean? I have an exact same issue.

Comment: No, sorry, I never did find a way